# Plugin for finding tags from content of post in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am making one web-app using cakephp.

In that i want to use plug-in which can automatically find tags from content which is written by user so that user needn't have to write tags manually and if he/she wants to add more tags then he/she can add manually.
And my question is that is:
Is there any plug-in available for that in cakephp and if there is than how can i use that in my application????

Comment: I doubt there is a plugin that specific. Also, how would it know what words are supposed to be tags?

Comment: i referred tagscrowed.com in that they decide tags on bases of occurrence of words...